# GCP Compute Engine Seamless Upgrade using HTTP Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on an application that is hosted on GCP compute engine, currently I have 1 version for the application but in the future I need to be able to update the version of this application and seamlessly this update gets reflected on the VMS without the need to stop them each time and having a lot of down time. I am using google http load balancer to distribute traffic among virtual machines.

Any ideas for best practices in such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

I think as a best practice you might need to create a managed instance group, and link it to the load balancer backend.

You can follow the following steps:

1- First stop the VMs. 
2- Create a base image from the stopped VM.
3- Use this image to create an instance template. 
4- Use this instance template to create the managed instance group. 
5- Make sure that the Load Balancer backend points to the desired managed instance group.

In case of updating to a new version, then you can create a new template for the new image and update the instance group to use the new template. In case of automatic updating GCP restarts the VMs in the managed instance group one by one therefore you won’t encounter any downtime.

Comment: I tried this solution but it seems that there is a problem with the connection between the managed instance group and the load balancer, any ideas?

Comment: In general the google load balancer takes few minutes to propagate, but you might also need to make sure that you allow http traffic to the instance group